# stuck with checking a winning condition and defining a function to move in python game

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I'm working on a Tic Tac Toe game with a custom grid size and a custom length of the winning line (from input).

The winning conditions that I have, check if there are N-times of the same player's letter horizontally, vertically or diagonally but they don't see if the moves are next to each other (so if they make a line). They only check if there's particular amount of same letter throughout the length of the grid.

I'd appreciate any tips on this.

```
#find the winner based on row, colum or diagonal downward/upward
def winnerFind(board, player, winLineLength):

    tempVar=[]
    for g in range(len(board)):
        if listSum(board[g]) == winLineLength or listSum(board[g]) == -winLineLength:
            print(player, "wins!")
            exit()

    for t in range(len(board)):
        for u in range(len(board)):
            tempVar.append(board[u][t])
        if listSum(tempVar)== winLineLength or listSum(tempVar)== -winLineLength:
            print(player, "wins!")
            exit()
        else:
            tempVar=[]
    tempVar=[]

    for a in range(len(board)):
        tempVar.append(board[a][a])
    if listSum(tempVar)== winLineLength or listSum(tempVar)== -winLineLength:
        print(player, "wins!")
        exit()

    tempVar=[]
    for s in range(len(board)):
        tempVar.append(board[-s-1][s])
    if listSum(tempVar)== winLineLength or listSum(tempVar)== -winLineLength:
        print(player, "wins!")
        exit()
```

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range` suggests you are trying to access an item in the list that doesn't exist - I.e. if your list has 4 items trying to do `my_list[6]` will give this error. If you are new to Python, it's worth knowing that list indexes start at 0 - so for the list with four items, to access the 4th one would be `my_list[3]`.